# RBS error in web front end server 18642 when read data

Tags: 2010, rbs

We have  some content databases configured with RBS storage. This SharePoint farm has two web front end servers.

I found the below RBS errors frequently in event viewer on one particular web server, but  when I upload documents it works fine, there is no issue.

> Message ID:32, Level:ERR , Process:7488, Thread:22 Exception thrown:
>   Operation: StoreReadBlob BlobStoreId: 0 Log Time: 5/23/2016 7:09:21 PM
>   Exception: Microsoft.Data.SqlRemoteBlobs.RemoteBlobStoreException: The
>   blob store  threw an exception. The exception
>   thrown is saved in InnerException. --->
>   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The network path was not found
>   at System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlFileStream.OpenSqlFileStream(String path,
>   Byte[] transactionContext, FileAccess access, FileOptions options,
>   Int64 allocationSize)    at
>   System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlFileStream..ctor(String path, Byte[]
>   transactionContext, FileAccess access, FileOptions options, Int64
>   allocationSize)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.BlobStores.FilestreamBlobStore.FilestreamReaderStream..ctor(String
>   filestreamPathName, CommittableTransaction transaction, Byte[]
>   transactionCtx, Boolean asyncReadDisabled)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.BlobStores.FilestreamBlobStore.FilestreamStoreLibraryBase.ReadBlob(Byte[]
>   storePoolId, Byte[] storeBlobId)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.BlobStores.BlobStore.ReadBlobInternal(Request request) 
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- ExceptionType:      BlobStore ExceptionCode:      BlobStoreUnhandledException Request
>   Information: Operation:          StoreReadBlob Request: Request 77 for
>   OpenReadableBlobStream Request Configuration not set. Command Details:
>   FetchBlobCommand    : Request 77  , CheckedConfigVersion: Undefined,
>   RetryNeeded: False, RetryAttempts: 3 BlobDetails: BlobStoreId 1,
>   StorePoolId 0x01000000, StoreBlobId 0x001cc3000000155c2d210b3936767f7f
>   Session Information not set. Provider Session Information: Provider
>   Session Info: ProviderSession:         ProviderSession. Id: <1>, Name:
>   , Type: , StoreVersion: <1.0.0.0>,
>   Location:

Comment: are you using network location to store blob storage?

Comment: in sql server there is rbs store

Comment: Please check the steps in given link below.

Answer (score 1):

Please verify the steps you had followed to install the RBS on your WFE server.

[Experience of Configuring Remote Blob Storage (RBS) with SharePoint 2010](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tejasr/2011/03/31/experience-of-configuring-remote-blob-storage-rbs-with-sharepoint-2010/)

Please let me know if it did not work for you.

Comment: rbs configuration and uploading documents to rbs store it working,but in web front end server i saw above errors , recently we changed the ip of web front end server

Comment: If you are able to ping the SQL machine in WFE machine than please check the damn firewall..

Comment: HI Hardik, we configured RBS according to best practise but in web front end servers many times RBS errors are appearing like above

Comment: Please check here if you can get something for you...https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4936521d-f12e-458e-8385-1e916349c84c/sharepoint-2010-rbs-cant-add-file-larger-than-1mb-the-network-name-cannot-be-found?forum=sharepointadminprevious